# Opening and closing EXE files through C# with a timer .NET

Tags: c#, .net, timer, openfiledialog

I've made an application that opens a filedialog when the browse button is pressed, and I can select up to 5 exe's and when I press start it starts them all at the same time.. Simple right?

I need to make it so when I press start it starts the softwares but it closes them again after a certain ammount of time, and it gets that time from the users valie that they input in a textbox.. I dont really know how to connect the Process.Start(FileName) to a timer with the textboxes and the timer.

How would I build the structure for this? i.e

Create a timer.
use the timer interval to set a certain ammount of milli seconds.
connect the timer with the code

Thats how I see the application being built, I was going tot ry it out but didnt know where to start.

[This is what the application looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZLFN.png)

Comment: I think all you described is doable. Start with the basics, break the problem down into smaller chunks and try to program your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, let a timer run and then after x milliseconds, issue a [Process.Kill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to them.

You could also do something like the following, using separate threads for each:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    // start the process and keep track of it
    var theProcess = Proces.Start(one of the porcesses);

    // sleep for your desired number of milliseconds.
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    // end the process (violently :)
    theProcess.Kill();
});
```

If you have your exes in a list, you could also do similar to the above with a Parallel.ForEach():

```
 Parallel.ForEach(filenames, (file) => 
{
    var theProcess = Process.Start(file);
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    theProcess.Kill();
});
```

Comment: I see where you are coming from but how do I hook up the users input interval to the software do I do something like timer.interval(); maybe?

Comment: @Joehl i keep getting the error cannot convert string to int from this

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            var firstProcess = Process.Start(textBoxFirst.Text);
            Thread.Sleep(MinTextBoxFirst.Text);
        }

Comment: @JonathanCoal As I can see in your comment. You try to set the `Sleep` method with the value of the TextBox, which is always a string. Just convert it with `int.TryParse(...)`.